# Angular velocity along a fixed rotational axis in space

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-velocity

I've been having some trouble getting my head around angular velocity and it's tangential movement,

From what I think I understand the angular velocity has always a direction which is perpendicular to that of the circular movement at constant speed $v$.

What I can't understand from my books is if that implies that there is a movement that goes "forward", what I mean is, if I have an object in space with a fixed axis of rotation and it moves at a constant angular speed, will the object move forward (or backwards) in space?

If this isn't the right place to ask I'm sorry

I hope I could make myself clear and thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The   angular velocity ${\boldsymbol \omega}$ vector of a rigid body  tells you that  if ${\bf r}_1$ and ${\bf r}_2$ are any pair of  points in the body with velocities ${\bf v}_1$ and ${\bf v}_2$ respectively,  then the  difference in their velocity vectors  is
$$
{\bf v}_2- {\bf v}_1 = {\boldsymbol \omega}\times ({\bf r}_2-{\bf r}_1),
$$
where the "$\times$" denotes the vector product. That there exists a  ${\boldsymbol \omega}$ for any motion of the body follows solely from the requirement that, in a rigid body, the distance $|{\bf r}_2-{\bf r}_1| $ between  any two points does not change as it moves .

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right answer is that the object will move forward in space.
If I have a point on the object moving at constant speed v, then the tangential velocity is v and the angular velocity is v/r.
The direction of the tangential velocity is always perpendicular to the direction of the angular velocity, so if the object moves at constant angular velocity, the tangential velocity will be constant and the object will move forward in space.

Answer (score 0):

> if I have an object in space with a fixed axis of rotation and it
> moves at a constant angular speed, will the object move forward (or
> backwards) in space?

No. The arrow of the angular velocity doesn't mean any translational movement of the object. It is only a usual convention to indicate the plane, direction (CW or CCW) and magnitude of rotation.

It can be replaced for a matrix. Instead of $\mathbf v = \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf r$, it is possible to write: $\mathbf v = \boldsymbol \Omega \mathbf r$, where $\Omega$ is the antisymmetric matrix:

\begin{vmatrix}
0&-\omega_z&\omega_y\\
\omega_z&0&-\omega_x\\
-\omega_y&\omega_x&0\\
\end{vmatrix}

Using the rule of matrix multiplication with the vector $\mathbf r = (x,y,z)$ we get the same vector $\mathbf v$ obtained by using the rule of the cross product.